# Number of times a video has been streamed via Azure Media Services

Tags: azure-media-services

Is it possible to determine the number of times a video in Azure Media Services has been requested/streamed via it's published URL.

Thanks

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether you use a CDN in front of the streaming unit. If so, you can only track viewing numbers via CDN. Our Azure CDN offers that capability. We don't track viewing numbers on streaming unit at the moment. Another option is to track on your client devices. Usually there are monitoring framework built in for players.

Cheers,
Mingfei yan